# Get public receipt link after payment via PayPal Checkout-Python-SDK

Tags: python, paypal, checkout, receipt

Trying to implement payments with Checkout-Python-SDK with requirement to provide the public link to detailed receipt to payer. Creating order on client, capturing it on server and everything is fine except I don't mind how to point user to his recipt.

There is known endpoint `https://www.paypal.com/receipt/?id={paypal_invoice_id}`, but it seems to work with **invoices** only (not **orders** or **payments**). [Checkout-Python-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-Python-SDK/tree/develop/paypalcheckoutsdk) does not support invoices (yet?) and previous [Paypal-Python-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK#paypal-checkout-v2) works with API v1 only and is "in the process of being deprecated".

Anyway I can create invoice by hand with [API v2](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/invoicing/v2/#invoices_payments) but should I? Invoices workflow looks too complex just for receipt link. So, **is there any way to get receipt link after checkout**?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Practically everyone with this requirement implements a normal PayPal checkout, and serves the detailed receipt at www.yourwebsite.com/orderconfirmation/your_order_id , or similar.

That is simply how things are done.

---

The PayPal invoice workflow is for a different use-case than checkouts, and so no, it should not be used unless you specifically need to send an invoice.

Comment: Order information on "mysite.com" can not be positioned as receipt at all, because "receipt" assumes that it is provided by fiscal institution with corresponding authority (in our case it is approved payment gateway) so the end user could trust it. Also I'm asking for it because Stripe, for example, provides receipt url for any payment

Comment: For PayPal payments there are emailed receipts, and transaction details viewable in the paypal.com accounts. But not public URLs.